# Leave out column in a angular datatable from ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-datatables

I want to use ng-repeat directive only for some specified column of a datatable

for example:

```
  <table id="coordinateconto" datatable="ng-binding"  dt-options="controllerCoo.dtOptions"
                    class="table table-bordered table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
  <tr>
     <th></th>
     <th>{{'Stato' | translate}}</th>
     <th>{{'Cin Int.' | translate}}</th>
     <th>{{'CIN' | translate}}</th>
     <th>{{'ABI' | translate}}</th>
     <th>{{'CAB' | translate}}</th>
     <th>{{'N. Conto' | translate}}</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="coo in controllerCoo.coordinate">
     <tr>
         <td data-dt-column='0'></td>
         <td data-dt-column='1'>{{coo.stato}}</td>
         <td data-dt-column='2'>{{coo.cinint}}</td>
         <td data-dt-column='3'>{{coo.cin}}</td>
         <td data-dt-column='4'>{{coo.abi}}</td>
          <td data-dt-column='5'>{{coo.cab}}</td>
          <td data-dt-column='6'>{{coo.idRapporto}}</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to exclude data-dt-column='0' from ng-repeat.

Comment: I think your ng-repeat should be place on the <tr> tag it would fit more there. We need more information about what you want to do with that '0' column. You can't exclude a td from a ng-repeat but depending on what you really want we may suggest something that would fit you :)

Comment: with this implementation the datatable has a problem, it doesn't fit well...I think that the problem is in the ng-repeat cycle. '0' column is used to show details in a responsive way